# I have a constructor on a subclass that includes an arraylist and the call to the constructor is giving me an error using Java

Tags: java, arraylist

So I have a PersonData class that holds: first name, last name, address and phone number.

I am supposed to create a subclass called CustomerData that adds a customer number, a boolean on whether the customer wants to be on a mailing list and a transaction list. The transaction list is supposed to be a arrayList of long integers.

These are some of the instructions:
 Write a non-argument constructor that sets all variables (including inherited ones) to empty strings and transactions to an empty ArrayList (but not null!)
 Write a constructor that takes all the data about customer as parameters (name, address, etc., total of 7 parameters) and initializes member variables. When working with transaction field, don’t forget to create a deep copy of the object that is given to you as an argument.

Here is the code I have for PersonData:

```
public class CustomerData extends PersonData implements Cloneable {

static int nextCustomerNumber = 0;
private int customerNumber;
boolean mailingList;
ArrayList<Long> transactions;

/**
 * No-arg constructor
 */
public CustomerData() {
    super();
    customerNumber = nextCustomerNumber++;
    mailingList = true;
    transactions = new ArrayList<Long>();
}

/**
 * Constructor that takes in all the values used
 *
 * @param lname last name that is inherited from PersonData
 * @param fname first name that is inherited from PersonData
 * @param addy address that is inherited from PersonData
 * @param number phone number that is inherited from PersonData
 * @param mList the mailing list boolean
 * @param t the array list for transactions
 */
public CustomerData(String lname, String fname, String addy, String number, boolean mList, ArrayList<Long> t) {

    super(lname, fname, addy, number);
    customerNumber = nextCustomerNumber++;
    mailingList = mList;
    transactions = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < t.size(); i++) {
        transactions.add(t.get(i));
    }
}
```

In my main file, CustomerDemo, I am trying to call the constructor with the parameters, I get the following errors (in Netbeans), Illegal Start of Expression, Illegal Start of Type,  and ";" expected.

Here's the code:

```
public class CustomersDemo {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    CustomerData customer = new CustomerData();
    CustomerData customer2 = new CustomerData("Wayne", "Bruce", "Gotham City", "548-547-5846", true, {1,2,3});
}
```

I would guess it has to do with the way I am trying to put data in the arrayList. I have looked on several sites and in my textbook, all I am seeing it using .add and .set to put things in an arraylist.

Not sure what to do, any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Java doesn't convert `{1,2,3}` into a `List` for you automatically. You'll need to do that yourself.

Comment: E.g., `Arrays.asList(1,2,3)`

Comment: Or just make it a varargs parameter.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should not require from input any kind of implementation. It is much better to use interface or abstract class instead.

```
public CustomerData(String lname, String fname, String addy, String number, boolean mList, List<Long> t) {
    ....
}
```

Now you can use handy [`Arrays.asList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) method.

```
CustomerData customer2 = new CustomerData("Wayne", "Bruce", "Gotham City", "548-547-5846", true, Arrays.asList(1,2,3));
```

See also:

1. [Converting between an Array and a List in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/convert-array-to-list-and-list-to-array)

Comment: This is an assignment for a class and the teacher wants transactions to be an ArrayList

Comment: `transactions` still can be `ArrayList`. I was talking about last parameter in constructor `ArrayList<Long> t`. It can look like `List<Long> t` and everything works properly.

Comment: That is causing an error, but the program is not telling me what the error is...sigh, this is frustrating. I probably could have gotten help at school, but we got snow and school was closed

Comment: Maybe you need to add new `import java.util.List;`?